# reindex on a new daterange for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I am having some trouble reindexing my data on a certain date range. Some of the sources does not show anything for the begining of my desired range and I want to add it. Looking at tutorials and others work this should work but doesn't.

```
data={'date':['19-02-2020','20-02-2020','21-02-2020'], 'data':[1,3,8]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
idx = pd.date_range(start='02-17-2020',end='02-21-2020',freq='D')
df.reindex(idx)
```

It returns:

```
date        data    
2020-02-19     1
2020-02-20     3
2020-02-21     8
```

But should return:

```
date        data
2020-02-17   NaN
2020-02-18   NaN
2020-02-19     1
2020-02-20     3
2020-02-21     8
```

I have read many examples and can't find anything wrong with it. Please help.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Your code print your desired output in my Jupyter notebook. Where did you run code? and What is your python version?

Comment: I'm using pycharm and python 3.7

Comment: Mine python version is 3.7. Now, i discover that when i run all code in one cell, it prints your desired output. But, when i run it separately, it prints your output.

Comment: I have found a similar problem

Comment: The problem is that you have to write the code like this "df = df.reindex(idx)".